# Phonegap navigation

Tags: android, cordova

I am confused about how to architecture my phonegap application.

Do I use a single-page application wherein I load relevant views using ajax ?
Or should I use many local html files and keep navigating between them using href tags ? Also, window.location seems to load the second page in a browser window, which is undesirable. I want to have whole of my app running in the same webview.

How can I stay on the same webview, while navigating between the pages using javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a javascript framework like backbone or sencha touch. Jquery-mobile will work but everything will be encapsulated on one page